# BCP a table with multiple line in single column

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I need to BCP a table which contains three lines in a single column. For example:

```
ID  Name    Comments
---------------------
 1 | Sample |   "Hai.
             Hello.
         How."
```

But the final BCP output file is having three lines instead of one line:

```
1^|^Sample^|^Hai
Hello^|^
How^|^
```

BCP Query:

```
bcp table out table_one.bcp -c -t "^|^" -Q -User -Password.
```

Comment: What you are you expecting to see in your output when your source data contains newlines?

Comment: output having three values(rows) not single row. I want single row.

Comment: You should address the problem rather than the symptom. Fix your source data by replacing newlines with a delimiter.

Comment: we cant edit the source table.

Comment: Let's try again. Your **data** contains newlines. If you want your put output to contain something *different from your data*, you need to first decide *what that different something is*. So, what you do *want* to see when your data contains newlines?

Answer (score 1):

Try the command a little different

```
bcp "select * from db..table" queryout "C:\dir\file.bcp" -n -T -SServer
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows line separators (`{CR}{LF}`) in your source text and don't want those in the output file, you can replace them in a query with something of your liking (eg a space).

Consider the following snippet. The source data contains Windows line separators. In the query these are replaced with a space. You will see in the output file that there are no longer multiple lines for a source text. You should be able to run this snippet from SSMS.

```
CREATE TABLE ##t(header INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,txt VARCHAR(1024));
INSERT INTO ##t(txt)VALUES
('This is the first line.
This is the second line.
This is the third line'),
('Again the first line.
Again the second line.
Again the third line.');

DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(4000)='BCP "SELECT header,REPLACE(txt,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'' '') FROM ##t" QUERYOUT "C:\Temp\test_txt.txt" -c -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' -d ' + DB_NAME();
EXECUTE master.sys.xp_cmdshell @cmd;

DROP TABLE ##t;
```

The output file `C:\Temp\test_txt.txt`:

```
1   This is the first line. This is the second line. This is the third line
2   Again the first line. Again the second line. Again the third line.
```